# Using "not" in template event selector

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code tries to apply the click event if the element being clicked is not a `canvas` element. 
It is failing to do so, How can it be fixed?

```js
Template.myTemp.events({
  'click :not("canvas")': function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select all elements (`*`) that are not a `<canvas>` (`:not(canvas)`, no quotes):

```
Template.myTemp.events({
  'click *:not(canvas)': function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
});
```